# How implementation ionic filter bar on ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

Sample project ionic filter bar https://github.com/djett41/ionic-filter-bar this project use ionic 1
How implementation this project to ionic 2?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at [the 2 minutes tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) on how to use this site, If you have not already.  It will help You a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Its been replaced with the searchbar directive. Its in their docs here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/